# Get profile image from facebook oAuth in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, facebook-graph-api, oauth

I have read the following post [Post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4859219/getting-user-profile-picture-using-facebook-c-sharp-sdk-from-codeplex) and followed ak7's answer to get the url of fb image, but when i browse to the url, it shows a photo with grey background and a question mark. Then i tried to follow the [Second post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059384/why-new-fb-api-2-4-returns-null-email-on-mvc-5-with-identity-and-oauth-2) Mike Troinfo's answer and added picture as a parameter to query string, but the info variable doesn't have any parameter corresponding to image. Kindly help me in figuring out  a solution to get Users DP from facebook and store it in database

```
var loginInfo = await AuthenticationManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
WebResponse response = null;
    string pictureUrl = string.Empty;
    try
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://graph.facebook.com/{0}/picture?type=large&redirect", loginInfo.email));
        response = request.GetResponse();
        pictureUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Before getting picture you have get access token of an user. Then you hit that url to get picture. See this link [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12104873/how-to-get-a-facebook-user-id-from-the-login-email-address).

[May be this link help you to get authentication token](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/11/asp-net-web-api-2-external-logins-social-logins-facebook-google-angularjs-app/).

And last of all you have to hit url like that.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/picture?redirect&access_token=CAACEdEose0cBACwZBfdwRTNjsxu1HRxyhQ78lIKGonbKaNRidTtM9QjiwuVuD6DzXsNL1qLGkc1P3sHFnElQ287I1VUBfamvdV0pfBs8dDgbOShqRh2UuviXyv4ZAZAcEEeqlZCKb39nGuTZAjssXCKhS8NZBXun9KfWwZCV29s32K37ajnYIOBelHh3gZCaJsixwXkhPXiQ5ZA2MY2flK4sz

using this you will get a json

```
{
 "data": {
  "is_silhouette": true,
  "url": "https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/hprofile-xfa1/v/t1.0-1/s200x200/10354686_10150004552801856_220367501106153455_n.jpg?_nc_eui=ARhjdKn0xJ2BpM9I6X_JD0UDCnmaSk6REHSU6yD01EeYw9avdnIb6dqiVr74&oh=3f560f9bf95ca602bb19c2d7b8870e1a&oe=57869A50"
  }
 }
```

Then you save the image from that url. There are lots of technique to save image from url.

```
{
byte [] data = webClient.DownloadData("https://fbcdn-sphotos-h-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/10555140_10201501435212873_1318258071_n.jpg?oh=97ebc03895b7acee9aebbde7d6b002bf&oe=53C9ABB0&__gda__=1405685729_110e04e71d9");

  using (MemoryStream mem = new MemoryStream(data)) 
  {
   using (var yourImage = Image.FromStream(mem)) 
   { 
      // If you want it as Png
       yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.png", ImageFormat.Png) ; 

      // If you want it as Jpeg
       yourImage.Save("path_to_your_file.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg) ; 
   }
 } 

}
```

For more details [see](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24797557/3127813) here.

Comment: Anik, thanks for your help, but still the same problem persists. The url it is returning is https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/rsrc.php/v2/yA/r/gPCjrIGykBe.gif

Comment: Can I see how do you hit the url?

Comment: Exactly like the first post and tried to change the request url according to your answer also

Comment: just give me an example. Whats the problem. may be i can find the error

Comment: the way you are doing is totally wrong. I have updated my answer hope it will help you.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help Anik, but nowadays, due to a lot other requirements, this work is put on hold. I will try after sometime and let you know. I really appreciate your effort and willingness to help.

Comment: Aniik, is this user access token or app access token??